# Syntax for [[maybe_unused]] attribute applied for type alias declaration

Tags: c++, attributes, c++17

Attempt to figure out correct syntax for `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute resulted in the [following code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YXksGzkn9lVZSS0L):

```
int main()
{
    typedef int X; // warning
    [[maybe_unused]] typedef int Y; // Ok
    using Z = int; // warning
    //[[maybe_unused]] using W1 = int; // error: expected ';' before 'using'
    //using [[maybe_unused]] W2 = int; // error: expected nested-name-specifier before '[' token
    using W3 [[maybe_unused]] = int; // Ok
    //using W4 = [[maybe_unused]] int; // error: an attribute list cannot appear here
}
```

All of it sudden it only works if written after the target type name. This seems strange since it is normally placed infront. Is this really a correct syntax or just come compiler glitch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the correct placement syntax according to the [grammar production](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.dcl#1):

```
alias-declaration:
    using identifier attribute-specifier-seq = defining-type-id ;
```

The optional *attribute-specifier-seq* comes after the identifier and before the `=`.

Comment: Now that's unfortunate. Also according to the linked page `typedef [[maybe_unused]] int Y;` should work too (*decl-specifier-seq:
 decl-specifier attribute-specifier-seq(opt)*), however it [yields an error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Pm3FFEJLGq9v1FKp).

Comment: @VTT Nope, it shouldn't. Read the grammar again.

Comment: What is the reason for this odd positioning of the attribute specifier?

Comment: @303 - Can't really say. The two papers (new alias syntax and attributes) were both for C++11. Each is based on C++03 and doesn't reference each other, so neither intended this placement. I also can't find an issue touching on it, and there's too much mailing to go though so I don't know if a rationale is publicly available.